# MappingException: Type can not be determined for java.util.Set

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

While running following program I am getting the error

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ListOfAddress)]

I added the `import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;`
But I am getting the same error

Can anyone please suggest me any option?

**HibernateTest.java**

```java
package src.com.hibernate.main;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.mapping.*;
import src.com.hibernate.Address;
import src.com.hibernate.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserName("Surendar");

        Address addr = new Address();
        addr.setStreet("Abith colony");
        addr.setCity("Chennai");
        addr.setState("TamilNAdu");
        addr.setPincode("600015");  

        Address addr1= new Address();
        addr1.setStreet("Anna Salai");
        addr1.setCity("Chennaimain");
        addr1.setState("TN");
        addr1.setPincode("600033");

        user.getListOfAddress().add(addr);
        user.getListOfAddress().add(addr1);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }

}
```

**UserDetails.java**

```
      package src.com.hibernate;


        import java.util.HashSet;
        import java.util.Set;

        import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.Table;

        @Entity
        @Table(name="UserTABLEaddress")
        public class UserDetails 
        {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            private int userId;     
            private String userName;

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            @ElementCollection
            private Set<Address> ListOfAddress = new HashSet();

            public Set<Address> getListOfAddress() {
                return ListOfAddress;
            }
            public void setListOfAddress(Set<Address> listOfAddress) {
                ListOfAddress = listOfAddress;
            }
            public int getUserId() {
                return userId;
            }
            public void setUserId(int userId) {
                this.userId = userId;
            }
            public String getUserName() {
                return userName;
            }
            public void setUserName(String userName) {
                this.userName = userName;
            }
```

**Address.java**

```
      package src.com.hibernate;
      import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

      @Embeddable
      public class Address 
         {

private String street;

private String city;

private String state;

private String pincode;
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}
public void setPincode(String pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="src.com.hibernate.UserDetails"/>
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your are mixing concepts. You try to use `@Embeddable` annotation in a class that is used in a `many-to-one` relationship. That is the cause of your error.

If you want to use `ListOfAddress` as an element collection, you have to define `Address` as an entity as well and configure the relationship correctly, for example:

```
...
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="address", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="userId"))
@Column(name="addresses")
private Set<Address> ListOfAddress = new HashSet<Address>();
...
```

And in Address Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address 
...
```

There are plenty of examples through internet.

Comment: Thanks For the reply And After Using the join columns also getting same error.   Do i Want to Create mapping file instead of using mapplig claa

Comment: My annotations was a suggestion, an example of how you could do the mapping. You have to adapt to your code. If you search google for "hibernate one to many annotations example" you will find some good examples of you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, when i changed my java compiler version from 1.6 to 1.5 it worked for me.

SO probably check if that is the case with you